# Form and SQL Validation using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, mysqli

When user clicks on the Save, check whether the data is successfully inserted record to the table, and display a proper message accordingly. If forms are empty then the error message should be shown and database should not have any record.

```
//SAVE

if (isset($_POST['SAVE'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $City = $_POST['city'];
    $query = "Insert Into Info Values('$Name','$City')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("query is failed" . mysqli_error($con));
    $Name = '';
    $City = '';
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {
        echo "record is saved";
    }else {
        echo "record is not saved";
    }
```

I can only do validation through php. I am not sure if I am doing this right. So far I can get the "record is saved" message on my form, but I cannot get the latter if the form are empty. It just make an empty record in my database.

Comment: you need to be using prepared statements, either via mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You could use `!empty` instead of `isset`, and check all three fields.

Comment: why not check the values too using `!empty` and `isset` inside your php

Comment: using !empty still adds the empty entry to my table

Comment: @Atheya empty like spaces?

Comment: Yes, then when I click on save again my page breaks saying that there is a duplicate entry 'Primary key'.

Comment: Checking `$_POST['SAVE']` will not tell you if the values are empty. My answer below will do the validation in PHP.

Comment: **Caution** This is open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested Code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['SAVE'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['city'])) {  // avoid Notices
    echo "Missing required submission data";
} elseif (!strlen(trim($_POST['name']))) {  // validate however you wish
    echo "Name data is not valid";  // explain however you wish
} elseif (!strlen(trim($_POST['city']))) {  // validate however you wish
    echo "City data is not valid";  // explain however you wish
} elseif (!$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db")) {  // declare and check for a falsey value
    echo "Connection Failure"; // $con->connect_error <-- never show actual error details to public
} elseif (!$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Info VALUES (?,?)")) {
    echo "Error @ prepare"; // $con->error;  // don't show to public
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['city'])) {
    echo "Error @ bind";  // $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
} elseif (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Error @ execute";  // $stmt->error;  // don't show to public
} else {
    echo "Insert Successful"; 
}
```

The validation conditions on the submission data ensure that the values are not empty and they are not completely comprised of whitespace characters.  If you wish to refine the validation requirement further, just update the conditions.

If you want to simply ensure that `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['city']` are not empty, you can replace the first three conditionals with

```
if (empty($_POST['SAVE']) || empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['city'])) {
    echo "Submission data is missing/invalid";
}...
```

If you don't use a prepared statement, then name values like `Paul O'Malley` will break your query.  Worse, if someone wants to try to run some injection attacks, your query is vulnerable.

Checking `affected_rows()` is unnecessary.  If there is no error message from the query execution, the INSERT query was a success.

The above suggestions are all best practices which I urge you to adopt.

Answer (score 1):

Checking `isset($_POST['SAVE'])` only tells you if "SAVE" is set. It does not tell you if the fields have values.

To do the validation in PHP, use something like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['SAVE'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $City = $_POST['city'];
    if ($Name && $City)
    {
       //...
       //code to insert data into the database goes here
       //...

       if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0) {
          echo "record is saved";
       }else {
          echo "record is not saved (error saving)";
       }
    } else {
       echo "record is not saved (input was empty)";
    }
}
```

The key being the `if ($Name && $City)` check.

Alternately, if you want to rely on mysql to reject the insert on blank values, then make sure the fields in the mySql table are not nullable and then change this part of your code: (but this would be moving the validation to MySql)

```
$Name = $_POST['name']?$_POST['name']:null;
$City = $_POST['city']?$_POST['city']:null;
```

Comment: Can't wait to see the explanation from the down voter. OP says he wants to do validation in PHP. This is the way to do that.

Comment: @mickmackusa OP said "I can only do vaildation through php." Further, the question has nothing to do with security. I did not write any queries in my answer. I did not show the world anything about writing queries. I used the OPs code. All i did was add an `if statement` to check that there was a value in `Name` and `City`. This answered the OPs question exactly.

Comment: @EvandelaCruz thank you very much. I am a beginner at php and this was confusing me.

Comment: @mickmackusa The bad query is irrelevant. Using prepared statements is irrelevant. On SO we answer the question. We don't make a bunch of assumptions.

Comment: @mickmackusa OK there you go. I'll look forward to your up vote

Comment: @Atheya You're welcome. Good luck! You should consider using prepared statements instead of string based inserts. Also, you probably want to validate this on the client side using javascript. Also, you probably want to add the `required` attribute to your HTML form inputs, to prevent them being submitted blank at all, and to utilize HTML5's built in validation.